# Using Euler's formula for cos/sin 12 degrees and cos/sin 48 degrees

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$(\cos12^\circ+i\sin12^\circ+\cos48^\circ+i\sin48^\circ)$. Using Euler's Formula, turn this into exponential form (i.e. something like $e^{i\frac{5\pi}{12}}$).

Would I need to use the $\cos$ and $\sin$ sum and difference formulas? I tried doing that and it became messy very quickly. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align*}
\cos 12^{\circ}=\cos(30^{\circ}-18^{\circ})&=\cos30^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}+\sin30^{\circ}\sin18^{\circ} \\
\sin 12^{\circ}=\sin(30^{\circ}-18^{\circ})&=\sin30^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}-\cos30^{\circ}\sin18^{\circ}\\
\cos 48^{\circ}=\cos(30^{\circ}+18^{\circ})&=\cos30^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}-\sin30^{\circ}\sin18^{\circ} \\
\sin 48^{\circ}=\sin(30^{\circ}+18^{\circ})&=\sin30^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}+\cos30^{\circ}\sin18^{\circ}
\end{align*}
Then, from trigonometric identities, we can reduce it as follows
\begin{align*}
\cos12^{\circ}+i\sin12^{\circ}+\cos48^{\circ}+i\sin48^{\circ}&=2\cos30^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}+i2\sin30^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}\\
&=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: You should reduce the expression in the parenthesis in order to know the imaginary part.

Comment: I meant to say: If the statement was: $$(\cos12^{\circ}+i\sin12^{\circ}+\cos48^{\circ}+i\sin48^{\circ})^6$$, would the imaginary part equal $1$ as well?

Comment: In such a case we have 
\begin{align*}
\text{Im}\left[\left(\cos12^{\circ}+i\sin12^{\circ}+\cos48^{\circ}+i\sin48^{\circ}\right)^6\right]&=\text{Im}\left[2^{6}e^{i\pi}\cos^6\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)\right]\\
&=-64\cos^6\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: What you put down was actually the real part. :)

Comment: @MathyPerson: yes, we have
$$(\cos 12^{\circ}+i\sin 12^{\circ}+\cos 48^{\circ}+i\sin48^{\cir‌​c})^6=−64\cos^6\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Would an answer like $$e^{i\frac{\pi}{15}}+e^{i\frac{7\pi}{30}}$$ suffice? Because that is the simplest form I got to.

Comment: My goal was to find: $$(e^{i\frac{\pi}{15}}+e^{i\frac{7\pi}{30}})^6$$ but it became messy fairly quickly. How would you advise I simplify this?

Comment: @MathyPerson If you are doing this for a class, most professors will accept this as an answer. However, if you want is simplified even further, use the binomial theorem.